# CSS: Have an :active state style that will not be triggered on tap-scroll on handheld devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/lalka/full/MaqVvp/)**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.item {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;

  &:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }
}
```

So I got this small piece of code.

**The Problem:** when I try to scroll down the page using a mobile device (pressing the finger on the `.item` that is separated by the black border and moving it up or down) I get my `:active` state triggered.

**The Question:** How do I not trigger `:active` state when scrolling on a handheld, but still have this `:active` on usual `click` or `tap` event?

I tried using some of the **JavaScript** like that

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function() {
    $('.item').addClass('no-pointer');
});

$(document).on('touchend', function() {
    $('.item').removeClass('no-pointer');
});
```

And having `.no-pointer {pointer-events: none;}` in the **CSS**, but the active state was still triggered.

Any ideas?

**P.S.** Use a real handheld device to view this page so as you get the idea of the problem, not the Chromium emulator (Browserstack will work too).

Comment: Works as expected on android chrome  tablet